# In AWS, boto3 how can I list all reservations regardless of the tags and other values

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I want to list tags for all ec2 resources(customer-gateway | dhcp-options | image | instance | internet-gateway | network-acl | network-interface | reserved-instances | route-table | security-group | snapshot | spot-instances-request | subnet | volume | vpc | vpn-connection and vpn-gateway).

The following code lists all the resources for my ec2 client which ***have*** tags:

```
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='default')
ec2Client = session.client('ec2', region_name='eu-west-2') 
allTags = ec2Client.describe_tags()['Tags']
for tag in allTags:
    print tag
```

**PROBLEM**

The problem here is that only resources like in case of 'instances', the instances which do not have tags are not included. If there are 5 instances in ec2, 3 with tags and 2 without tags, the above code will list only those 3 instances with tags.

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

I want all the resources (instances, VPCs, subnet, security groups etc.), to be listed whether the tags are defined or not. If there are tags it shows tags, if not I still want it to be included in the result without tags.

One way is to use describe_xxx method for each resource to get the reservations and look for tags, but I would have to call it for every resource (like describe_instances(), describe_snapshots, describe_security_groups() etc.), which, in my opinion is not so cleaned and generic way solution.

**QUESTION**

Is there any way using boto3 library to list all the resources, if the resources have tags show the tags too if not then show the resources only?

Comment: I was referring to this documentation here: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, boto3 does not offer a `describe_all` method. To achieve your desired result, if I understand it correctly, you will have to separately describe all object types, i.e. `describe_vpcs`, `describe_instances`, etc, and then look for the tags in the resulting data structures.

For example,
One could construct a single data structure from all the resulting method calls (`describe_instances`, `describe_vpcs`, `describe_subnets`, etc.) which will look like:

```
{
  Vpcs: [{... Tags: [{...}]}]
  Instances: [{... Tags: [{...}]}]
  Subnets: [{... Tags: [{...}]}]
  ...
}
```

I believe this is the closest match to the object you are referring to in your question.